# The blessing for 600,000 Jews

Tags: history, blessing, number, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, state-of-israel

The Gemara ([Berakhot 58b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=58b&format=pdf)) mentions that upon seeing 600,000 Jews one says the blessing "Baruch...Chacham HaRazim" (Who knows all secrets), and this is halacha ([Sh.A. O.C. 224:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=720&hilite=)).

Does any know of any time in history (besides Har Sinai) when this has happened? I would think that such a large gathering liklier in the State of Israel, but has the blessing been said?

[A separate question would be how you even count such an event. Besides the sheer mass, we can't count Jews to begin with (perhaps we would go through ticket stubs).]

I'd love to hear if anything of the sort has been organized.

Comment: Well from that same gemara we see that Rav Chanina said it on 2 ppl so that another time ,but u are asking on the 600000 as opposed to the bracha.

Comment: I remember once (around 2006) there was a rally (maybe pro-Israel?) on the Mall in DC and they were estimating and trying to get to 600k, but fell short.

Comment: What about Meron during Lag BaOmer? Last year there were half a million Jews over there (myself not included), maybe they said it: http://www.jpost.com/Israel/Article.aspx?id=174455

Comment: And yet somehow, Reshuyot haRabbim were so common that Chazal still felt a need to make incredibly restrictive Gezeirot lest someone accidentally carry. I'd have to assume this Bracha was said all the time!

Comment: The Gemara there says that one of the Tanayim said it during the aliya leregel

Comment: @Aryeh In Meron, people come and go the entire 24 hour period of Lag B'Omer. There is not half a million people at one time.

Comment: @doubleaa ,why are you assuming that the 600k were jews.

Comment: @sam Who else was living in Israel? Recall that the first takkanot of Eiruvin were made by King Shlomo according to the Gemara. But my point stands for the Tanaaim as well.

Comment: @doubleaa Non jews maybe live there.

Comment: @sam Hundreds of thousands of them?! Recall that the entire population of Rome around Churban Bayit Sheni was only about a million.

Comment: @DoubleAA Isn't that 600,000 per day? Not all at once?

Comment: @Ariel Well, not all agree to 'per day', but you are right that it doesn't mean all at once. Touchee! I guess they didn't say the bracha all the time. :/

Comment: @DoubleAA I've seen a Tzemach Tzedek where he says that the whole Gezeira of Rava (or was it Rabba) was to avoid carrying in a karmelis (kind of a gezeira to a gezeira).

Comment: @DoubleAA Also, the Gemara there says that there was no "ochlosia(?)" in Bovel. It's a Gemara used by those who argue on the 600,000 requirement for a reshus harabim, as there were quite clear Reshuious harabim in Bavel (as in the debate in the beginning of Eiruvin whether one must close the door of a public domain to make it private, and they brought a proof from Nahardah, or the Mavoi Akum, etc.)

Comment: @DoubleAA 600000 isn't mentioned in the gemara, and there are different views on it, but it would probably mean in an entire area in a day, such as a large city.

Comment: @ArielK Of course it's not in the Gemara. The Gemara wouldn't say such incredulous things.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Almost anything can be justified with sufficiently _dachuk svaras_.

Comment: @DoubleAA *not* requiring 600,000 people is dachuk?

Comment: @DoubleAA The view in the rishonim of 600k may be difficult, but since its discussing a city, it still wouldn't be like seeing 600k together for a bracha.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I mean understanding שמא יעבירנו ד אמות ברשות הרבים as a Karmelit to be very dachuk.

Comment: @ArielK I already conceded that point [above](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19122/the-blessing-for-600-000-jews?noredirect=1#comment47305_19122).

Answer (score 4):

At the rally about drafting yeshiva bachurim on March 2, 2014, over 600,000 Jews attended, and the blessing Chacham HaRazim was said. ([two](http://www.jdn.co.il/news/316299) [links](http://www.jpost.com/National-News/Hundreds-of-thousands-turn-out-for-mass-haredi-demonstration-in-Jerusalem-344003))

The blessing was led by Rav Baruch Mordechai Ezrachi, and introduced by Rav  Elimelech Tirnauer. ([Hamodia](http://hamodia.com/2014/03/02/multitude-rallies-protest-governments-anti-religious-policies/))

Comment: Oh, the irony of such Israeli unity! Is there anymore info on this. Only the headline mentions the bracha was said, but the article doesn't give any explanation (i.e., how did they know the protestors were 600K at the time, who authorized saying the bracha, etc.)

Comment: @Aryeh I added more info (from Hamodia)

Comment: One of your links claims there was really only 300000 and hence the bracha was levatalla I guess.

Answer (score 3):

[According to a contemporary news report](http://www.jewishpress.com/news/breaking-news/half-million-at-rav-ovadias-funeral/2013/10/07/), on October 7, 2013 Rabbi Ovadia Yosef was laid to rest with 850,000 people attending the funeral.

Comment: I've seen many different estimations. These things tend to be over-estimated in the initial reports. Can you source definitively that more than 600K were there?

Comment: What @DoubleAA said. Also, were they gathered in one place (or, say, 'attending' via watching and listening on screens)? And do you know about whether the _b'racha_ was said (by anyone of halachic authority, say)? In any event, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and post good questions and answers, and may we share _s'machos_ in the future.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if the blessing was said. It could be that they were spread over a large enough area that one wouldn't be able to see all of them in one shot (unless one were to be in a helicopter).

Comment: It seems like it answers the first half (that more than 600,000 people came) while not answering the (IMO more important) second half (whether a bracha was said).

Comment: I didn't see any report that less than 600k people were there. However, they were spread out over many streets, so not sure what would qualify for the beracha. See the pictures here: http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/70336000/jpg/_70336470_70336469.jpg http://news.nationalpost.com/2013/10/08/rabbi-ovadia-yosefs-death-stirs-up-israeli-politics-brings-jerusalem-to-a-standstill-as-700000-people-attend-funeral/ http://www.jewishpress.com/news/breaking-news/half-million-at-rav-ovadias-funeral/2013/10/07/

Comment: @ArielK, in what context would 600,000 people fit in a single venue?

Comment: I did see someone write that he said the Berachah for the first time in his life in the context of yesterday's funeral.

Comment: @SethJ I don't know how together they need to be. But maybe they need to be in one specific area that's visible at once as opposed to spread out over many different streets.

Comment: (i.e. in an square that can fit 775 people on each side, so say 1550 feet per side.)

Comment: @ArielK, whether we go with your estimate [or a more formal one](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_much_square_feet_does_a_person_take_up_standing_up), that strikes me as rather unrealistic.

Comment: @sethJ, that's a building code, and it only adds a couple inches. at some events, 1 person gets even less than 4 square feet.

Comment: @ArielK FWIW the Temple mount is about equivalent to 1250 feet per side, so it would have to be _totally_ full to [get a blessing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19122/the-blessing-for-600-000-jews#comment47261_19122).