# Is there any special mitzvah connected with the upcoming “March for Israel” rally on November 14 at the National Mall in Washington DC?

Tags: halacha, parshanut-torah-comment, history, blessing, tzibur-community

Upon reflection, the last time there was a potentially world altering convergence of Jews in the United States was for the **[Freedom Sunday for Soviet Jewry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Sunday_for_Soviet_Jews)** Rally on December 6, 1987. It was estimated that at that time, 250,000 Jews met together at the National Mall and that demonstration of unity changed the course of history.

The hope is that this upcoming rally on November 14, 2023, *which will coincide with Rosh Chodesh Kislev*, in support of Israel will greatly surpass even that historic event. **Perhaps, we may be fortunate to even see 600,000 Jews assembled together at one time and one place in unity!**

Is there any special mitzvah or blessing mentioned in the Torah which they can observe together that will truly demonstrate the unity and oneness of the Community of Israel (מי כעמך כישראל גוי אחד בארץ) 2-Samuel 7:23 and Ezekiel 37:22) on that day?

Comment: Not really a direct answer, but the Gemara in Taanis 11a says two things: 1) when the Jewish people are in distress, one should not go home and think "it'll be alright", 2) a person should be distressed together with the community that experiences suffering.

Comment: @Shmuel I was thinking more along the lines of tractate Brachot 58a. PS: Buses are being arranged and you could learn on the bus ride the whole way. Check your local Jewish Federation.

Comment: Related: "[The blessing for 600,000 Jews](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19122/1368)"

Comment: @YaacovDeane would be great if they livestreamed it :)

Comment: @TamirEvan Exactly what was on my mind. I many people who attended the Soviet Jewry Rally. They all commented that the G-dly presence, the Kedusha they sensed there at the time was a life changing event. Bli neder, I hope to see many from the MiYodeya community there.

Comment: In the gemara in Brachos מי כעמך כישראל גוי אחד בארץ is mentioned as one of the pesukim "worn" by השם in His tefillin! In combo with this mitzva's association with וראו כל עמי הארץ כי שם ה' נקרא עליך ויראו ממך, maybe all the men should come wearing that! (I myself might not yet be on that madreiga :-) )

Comment: @EraserX Hope to see you there.

Comment: Shmuel, there are plans in the works to livestream it. Check the various postings in a few days

Comment: @YaacovDeane interesting: https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/israel-news/2239461/gedolim-sign-kol-korei-bnei-torah-should-not-attend-washington-rally.html

Comment: @Shmuel I saw it. A few points worth noting is that the published opinion of these five individuals (their individual opinions) is only aimed at those who follow their specific minhag, like they emphasize, “the opinion of our Rabbanim, z’tl whose mesorah we hold, warned us from joining with religious streams who are far from the Derech HaTorah and Mesorah”. There are many other traditional, Orthodox schools of thought that do not follow the traditions of those signatories. In the end, all Orthodox Jews accept the words of Isaiah the Prophet that, “Your entire nation are righteous.”

Answer (score -3):

בס״ד

Today, Rosh Chodesh Kislev, 1 Kislev 5784, the Community of Israel (עדת ישראל) stand together, here in Washington DC, the Capitol city of the United States (ארצות הברית), which corresponds to the bottom of the world (למטה מטה עד אין תכלית) together with the more than 600,000 soldiers of the Israeli Army (חיילים מבית דויד צבאות הגנה לישראל), in the Holy Land, the Land of Israel, which corresponds to the top of the world (ארץ הקודש, ארץ ישראל, למעלה מעלה עד אין קץ), all of them righteous, like the Prophet of the final Redemption says, ([Isaiah 60:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.60.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) (ועמך כלם צדיקים), together as one, like the Prophet Samuel says ([2 Samuel 7:23](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.7.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), “And who is like Your people, Israel, a nation, one, in the world…” (ומי כעמך ישראל גוי אחד בארץ).

And standing together as one also recalls the time of the first redemption, when we all camped together at Mount Sinai as one nation like it says ([Exodus 19:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.2?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=he)), “…and there Israel encamped before the Mountain.” ([ויחן-שם ישראל נגד ההר](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.2?lang=bi&with=Or%20HaChaim&lang2=he)), corresponding to G-d, who is one, like we say twice each day, “Hear, Israel, the L-rd, our G-d, the L-rd is one.” (שמע ישראל י״י אלהינו י״י אחד)

Today, like then, we stand together to call out like the first Human Being ([Genesis 1:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.27?lang=bi&aliyot=0)), men and women, Adam HaRishon, on the day of his creation, ([Psalms 95:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.95.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) saying [“Come, let us sing out to the L-rd, flocking to the Rock of our salvation.](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.95.1?lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=he)” To reveal how G-d, the source of all life, is King over all, like is said ([Numbers 14:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.14.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [14:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.14.28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) “But I am life, and the glory of the L-rd will fill the whole world.” (אולם חי-אני וימלא כבוד-יהוה את-כל-הארץ) (חי-אני נאום יהוה)

And with this intention we say the three-fold blessings passed down to us from our forefathers, through Moses our teacher like is found in tractate [Berachot 58a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.58a.3?lang=bi) and also [Sanhedrin 94a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.94a.4-7?lang=bi), which associates this to both the conclusion of the War of Gog and Magog and the final Redemption.

ברוך אתה י״י אלהינו מלך העולם חכם הרזים.

ברוך אתה י״י אלהינו מלך העולם שברא כל אלו לשמשני.

ברוך אתה י״י אלהינו מלך העולם שהחינו וקימנו והגיענו לזמן הזה.

Blessed are You, L-rd, our G-d, King of the Universe, Sage of the Secrets.

Blessed are You, L-rd, our G-d, King of the Universe , who created all this to officiate for Me.

Blessed are You, L-rd, our G-d, King of the Universe, who caused us to live, and who sustained us, and who caused us to reach this time.

Comment: One should NOT say those blessings without consulting an Orthodox Rabbi. The blessing of "חכם הרזים" is only to be said over a crowd of 600,000 Jews, not less.